# How does order() for character variable work in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to reorder rows in my table according to a character variable (`stage` in my example). If I first save the desired order (`order(dt1$stage)`) to a variable and then apply it as `dt1[myorder, stage]` - it works fine. But when I try to do the same inline, like `dt1[order(dt1$stage), ]`, the order is different! Must be something very basic I'm missing...

```
dt1 <- fread('
id stage pos
 1 I       1
 2 II      2
 3 III     5
 4 IV      6
 5 IIa     3
 6 IIb     7
 7 IIIa    8
 8 IIIb    4
 9 IVa     9
10 IVb    10')

sort(dt1$stage) # OK
# I II IIa IIb III IIIa IIIb IV IVa IVb

myorder <- order(dt1$stage)
dt1[myorder         , stage] # OK
# I II IIa IIb III IIIa IIIb IV IVa IVb

dt1[order(dt1$stage), stage] # different!
# I II III IIIa IIIb IIa IIb IV IVa IVb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing a `fast` `order` instead of the `base::order`.  According to `?data.table::order`

> Note that queries like x[order(.)] are optimised internally to use data.table's fast order.

> Also note that data.table always reorders in "C-locale" (see Details). To sort by session locale, use x[base::order(.)].

> data.table implements its own fast radix-based ordering.

> data.table always reorders in "C-locale". As a consequence, the ordering may be different to that obtained by base::order. In English locales, for example, sorting is case-sensitive in C-locale. Thus, sorting c("c", "a", "B") returns c("B", "a", "c") in data.table but c("a", "B", "c") in base::ord

If we want to replicate the `sort` from `base`, use the `base::order`

```
dt1[base::order(stage)]$stage
#[1] "I"    "II"   "IIa"  "IIb"  "III"  "IIIa" "IIIb" "IV"   "IVa"  "IVb"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now it's clear! So, if I wanted to reorder the whole table, instead of `setorder(dt1, stage)` I should use `dt1 <- dt1[base::order(stage),]`, right?

Comment: @VasilyA yes, but it may be slow compared to `setorder` for big datasets